# How to split the domain of the bottom axis?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to get a SVG of a rates curve. A good example of what I would like to represent is here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRQZL.jpg
Here is my code for the bottom axis:

```
const xscale = d3.scaleLinear()
                 .domain([0, 1, 1, 30])
                 .range([0, 200, 200, 1000]);
const yscale = d3.scaleLinear()
                 .domain([0, 1.5])
                 .rangeRound([height, 0]);

/*
--- Drawing the axis using the scales declared previously ---
*/

const xaxis = d3.axisBottom()
                .scale(xscale)
                .tickValues([0.083, 0.167, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 20, 30])
                .tickFormat(function(d) {
                                          const tick_r = ['1M', '2M', '3M', '6M', '1Y', '2Y', '3Y', '5Y', '7Y', '10Y', '20Y', '30Y']
                                          return tick_r[d-1];});
const yaxis = d3.axisLeft()
                .scale(yscale);
```

Unfortunately with this, the label gets delayed up to the 5th element on the list '1Y', so the '1Y' value shows up as '1M'. There are missing labels on both ends of the curve.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1VsH.png

What I want is for every data point along the curve the label as listed within the tickFormat callback function.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, your `tickFormat` is using the *datum* to get the elements in the `tick_r` array:

```js
const xscale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 1, 1, 30])
  .range([0, 100, 100, 500]);

const xaxis = d3.axisBottom(xscale)
  .tickValues([0.083, 0.167, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 20, 30])
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    const tick_r = ['1M', '2M', '3M', '6M', '1Y', '2Y', '3Y', '5Y', '7Y', '10Y', '20Y', '30Y']
    return tick_r[d - 1];
  });

xaxis(d3.select("svg").append("g"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500"></svg>
```

This makes little sense because you'll have things like `tick_r[0.083 - 1]`, `tick_r[0.167 - 1]`, `tick_r[0.25 - 1]` etc...

You should use the index instead:

```
.tickFormat(function(_, i) {
    const tick_r = ['1M', '2M', '3M' etc...]
    return tick_r[i];
});
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
const xscale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 1, 1, 30])
  .range([10, 100, 100, 490]);

const xaxis = d3.axisBottom(xscale)
  .tickValues([0.083, 0.167, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 20, 30])
  .tickFormat(function(_, i) {
    const tick_r = ['1M', '2M', '3M', '6M', '1Y', '2Y', '3Y', '5Y', '7Y', '10Y', '20Y', '30Y']
    return tick_r[i];
  });

xaxis(d3.select("svg").append("g"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500"></svg>
```